# One way communication between vm's?

Tags: linux, networking, vmware, virtualization

We have 3 vm's set up in ESXi on one machine, and on another machine (host OS = MS Server 2012) we have 5 machines set up in VMware Workstation 11.

From the Workstation VM's I can ping and ssh into all 3 ESXi vm's, but from the ESXi vm's I can't ping or ssh to the Workstation VM's. I have tried this with the firewall enabled and disabled on the MS Server.

All vm's are running CentOS 6.x, the ESXi machines are full desktops, the Workstation machines are minimal installs.

All 5 Workstation vm's have 2 way comms with each other, as do all 3 ESXi vm's but comms only go one way between the two types.

Ned ideas for troubleshooting this, wide searches of the net yielded nothing helpful that I could find, nor did posting this problem on the VMware forums.

Comment: Additional info: I can ping the same gateway from both sets of machines successfully.

Answer (score 0):

How is the networking setup for the Workstation VMs?  Sounds like they may be NAT-ed, which would render them invisible.

Comment: Workstation machine has (as I've been trying to figure this out) 4 nics at the moment, one each, NAT, custom (vmnet8), host only, and bridged. Esxi machines have two nic's one vm network, one outside network.